# Setting SKSpriteNodes position from custom SKSpriteNode class

Tags: swift, sprite-kit

I want to set the position of a `skspritenode`(`hero`) in my gamescene when I assign my class(`Character`) to it.

When its given the `CGPoints` `frame.midX` and `frame.midY` it doesn't know what frame its in reference to, so it shows up somewhere completely different.

Any idea how I can fix my class so that the `cPosition` will actually set the position of my `hero` in my gamescene ?

### Class code

```
class Character: SKSpriteNode{

    var cSize: CGSize
    var cColor: UIColor
    let cName: String
    let cTexture: SKTexture
    let cPosition: CGPoint

    init(cTexture: SKTexture,cSize: CGSize,cColor: UIColor, cName: String,cPosition: CGPoint){

        self.cSize = cSize
        self.cColor = cColor
        self.cName = cName
        self.cTexture = cTexture
        self.cPosition = cPosition

        super.init(texture: cTexture, color: cColor, size: cSize)
    }

    func jump(xForce: CGFloat, yForce: CGFloat){
        physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVector(dx: xForce, dy: yForce))            
    }
```

Method where my `Character` class is assigned to my `hero`:

```
     func addHero() {

            let hero = Character(cTexture: SKTexture(imageNamed: "testAvacado.png") ,cSize: CGSize(width: 68, height: 28), cColor: .blue, cName: "hero",
cPosition: CGPoint(x: frame.midX, y: frame.midY))

            hero.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(texture: hero.cTexture, size: hero.cSize)

            addChild(hero)
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually positioning your sprite, the `cPosition` variable does nothing at the moment. Change your `init` method like this:

```
var cSize: CGSize
var cColor: UIColor
let cName: String
let cTexture: SKTexture
//let cPosition: CGPoint

init(cTexture: SKTexture,cSize: CGSize,cColor: UIColor, cName: String,cPosition: CGPoint) {

    self.cSize = cSize
    self.cColor = cColor
    self.cName = cName
    self.cTexture = cTexture
    //self.cPosition = cPosition

    super.init(texture: cTexture, color: cColor, size: cSize)

    self.position = cPosition
}
```

Comment: Awesome this worked like a charm, I'm assuming this works because it assigns cPosition to the position of the node in the skview when its initialized? Vs before well i'm not really certain what was happening exactly. If you could elaborate I would be very thankful

Comment: Before you were assigning `cPosition` to a variable of the same name, but its just a variable, you could name it `blabla` for that matter, but you weren't actually assingning a position to the sprite, which in order to do you need to change its existing `position` variable.